# How to copy SSMS connections in dropdown to a new computer?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2016, ssms-2017

I'm getting an upgraded laptop at work and my old machine had SSMS 17.9 with several dozen dbengine connections with pwds in the dropdown for dbengine Connection.

Are these in the registry, ini file, Windows Credential manager?   I would like to be able to copy them to the new machine.  I'm even ok if I have to re-enter the passwords--the servernames are really a bigger deal to me.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export the registered servers.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that did it!

Answer (score 1):

1. In your source SSMS, in Registered Servers: right-click the server
   group that contains your connections > Tasks > Export...
2. Copy the exported file to the machine that contains the new SSMS
   instance.
3. On the new instance of SSMS, in Registered Servers: right-click the
   server group that will contain your connections > Tasks > Import...

Answer (score 1):

You can copy from the old computer to the new one from the following path:
`%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\18.0\UserSettings.xml`

(18.0 its the SSMS version, it may vary from each specific case)

Comment: This just worked for me with a v18 config file copied into the v19 config directory in another PC